# Why open the same one database with sqlalchemy, but get different, how can I update it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I write some tests with pytest, I want to test create user and email with post method.
With some debug, I know the issue is I open two databases in memory, but they are same database `SessionLocal()`.
So how can I fix this, I try `db.flush()`, but it doesn't work.

this is the post method code

```py
@router.post("/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(
    *,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db), #the get_db is SessionLocal()
    user_in: schemas.UserCreate,
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_superuser),
) -> Any:
    """
    Create new user.
    """
    user = crud.user.get_by_email(db, email=user_in.email)
    if user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400,
            detail="The user with this username already exists in the system.",
        )
    user = crud.user.create(db, obj_in=user_in)
    print("====post====")
    print(db.query(models.User).count())
    print(db)
    if settings.EMAILS_ENABLED and user_in.email:
        send_new_account_email(
            email_to=user_in.email, username=user_in.email, password=user_in.password
        )
    return user
```

and the test code is:

```py
def test_create_user_new_email(
    client: TestClient, superuser_token_headers: dict, db: Session # db is SessionLocal()
) -> None:
    username = random_email()
    password = random_lower_string()
    data = {"email": username, "password": password}
    r = client.post(
        f"{settings.API_V1_STR}/users/", headers=superuser_token_headers, json=data,
    )
    assert 200 <= r.status_code < 300
    created_user = r.json()
    print("====test====")
    print(db.query(User).count())
    print(db)
    user = crud.user.get_by_email(db, email=username)
    assert user
    assert user.email == created_user["email"]
```

and the test result is

```
>       assert user
E       assert None

====post====
320
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f0a9f660910>
====test====
319
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f0aa09c4d60>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not provide enough information to help you, the key issues are probably in what is hidden and explained by your comments.

And it seems like you are confusing sqlalchemy session and databases. If you are not familiar with these concepts, I highly recommend you to have a look at [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html).

But, looking at your code structure, it seems like you are using FastAPI.

Then, if you want to test SQLAlchemy with pytest, I recommend you to use pytest fixture with SQL transactions.

Here is my suggestion on how to implement such a test. I'll suppose that you want to run the test on your actual database and not create a new database especially for the tests. This implementation is heavily based on [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/e2365f25a213de44b9a2) (the author made a "feel free to use statement", so I suppose he is ok with me copying his code here):

```py
# test.py
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


from myapp.models import BaseModel
from myapp.main import app # import your fastapi app
from myapp.database import get_db # import the dependency

client = TestClient(app)

# scope="session" mean that the engine will last for the whole test session
@pytest.fixture(scope="session") 
def engine():
    return create_engine("postgresql://localhost/test_database")

# at the end of the test session drops the created metadata using fixture with yield
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def tables(engine):
    BaseModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    yield
    BaseModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)

# here scope="function" (by default) so each time a test finished, the database is cleaned
@pytest.fixture
def dbsession(engine, tables):
    """Returns an sqlalchemy session, and after the test tears down everything properly."""
    connection = engine.connect()
    # begin the nested transaction
    transaction = connection.begin()
    # use the connection with the already started transaction
    session = Session(bind=connection)

    yield session

    session.close()
    # roll back the broader transaction
    transaction.rollback()
    # put back the connection to the connection pool
    connection.close()

## end of the gist.github code

@pytest.fixture
def db_fastapi(dbsession):
    def override_get_db():
        db = dbsession
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            db.close()
    client.app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
    yield db


# Now you can run your test
def test_create_user_new_email(db_fastapi):
    username = random_email()
    # ...
```

Comment: `deps.get_db` is `def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()`, and `db: Session` is `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db() -> Generator:
    yield SessionLocal()`. and about `SessionLocal()` is `engine = create_engine(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)`, I'm sorry for this comment format.

Comment: You can edit your question with these snippets. But here, we can understand why they are not the same object. You create a new instance each time you call `SessionLocal`.

Comment: Thanks, I fix it with create one instance.